# Playing multiple videos simultaneously with WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, video, media, vlc

I have a 12-HD-monitor setup, using two Radeon FirePro W600 Graphic Cards (2GB RAM each), running with a Windows 10 OS, 16GB RAM, and a brand new i7-6th gen. CPU.

I'm trying to write a program that runs 4 videos across all the monitors (each video is stretched over 3 monitors), yet no matter what component I use (MediaPlayer, VLC.net...) When the 3rd video is loaded the videos start skipping frames.

The CPU and Memory stats indicate there's no problem with the system's resources, which peaks to just 20-30%.

What's the best way to play multiple videos simultaneously (smoothly) on a 12-monitor system, as described, using C#?

Comment: Are the videos all on separate threads? 25% of an i7 is 100% of a single core. I don't know the details, but also check that the video component is using hardware acceleration (using GPU).

Comment: Yes, each on a different thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was lack of VRAM. With 2GB VRAM for each Video Card, the computer can run 2-3 FullHD (1920X1080) monitors smoothly. There's no way to force a computer to use the system's memory for rendering the monitors, so that was our system's bottleneck.

By decreasing the monitors' resolution, we were able to run much more videos, much more smoothly, simultaneously on 12 monitors.